# Как правильно использовать две функции в работе с файлами Си

Tags: c, циклы

Столкнулся с проблемой.Не работают 2 цикла одновременно.К примеру,если я отключу один,то будет работать второй.Возможно,что проблема может быть в в текстовом файле,но я никак её не найду.В чем может быть проблема?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>




int main (void )
{

    FILE *file;
    char result_string[120];


    int vse = 0;
    int kr;
    file = fopen("FileX.txt","r");

    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return 0;
    }
    char c = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (c == ';')
            vse++;

   }
    printf("%d\n",vse);



    while(fgets(result_string,sizeof(result_string),file))
    {

        if(result_string[strlen(result_string)-1] == '.')
        {
            kr = 1;
            printf("%d",kr);
        }


    }



    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Текстовый файл

```
uses crt, dos, vbe30
var
   screen: Text;
   screen: Filter;

begin
 Crt.AssignCrt(screen);
 AssignCrt(screen);
 DosCrd(screen);
end.
```

Comment: Ну так вы в одном цикле проходите файл до конца (до `EOF`) и второму циклу уже нечего читать, потому что текущая позиция выставлена в конец файла. Либо закрывайте и открывайте файл заново, либо делайте `seek` в начало файла перед вторым циклом.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо за помощь,помогло!